# php page refresh once - opencart

Tags: php, opencart

im having a problem in my opencart website. i always want the customer who set delivery address non malaysia to always pay in USD.

the problem is they will choose MYR and choose non malaysia country and pay.

so i applied the below at catalog/controller/checkout/checkout.php

```
     $this->currency->set('MYR'); 
     if ($_SESSION['shipping_zone_id'] == '3528'){ 
     $this->currency->set('USD');
     }
```

the problem is for currency to go into session, it needed a page refresh, so i applied the below :

```
     $this->currency->set('MYR'); 
     if ($_SESSION['shipping_zone_id'] == '3528'){ 
     $this->currency->set('USD');
     $sec = "10";
     header("Refresh: $sec; url=index.php?route=checkout/checkout");
     }
```

the above yes refreshing the page, but it keep on refreshing the page. i want it to refresh only once.
plz advice

Comment: Show the `var_dump($_SESSION['shipping_zone_id']);` just before `header()`.

Comment: noting happen when i apply var_dump($_SESSION['shipping_zone_id']);

Comment: I hope you have commented/removed header line and replaced it with `die()` or `exit` function?

Comment: this is what i used   $this->currency->set('MYR'); 
     if ($_SESSION['shipping_zone_id'] == '3528'){ 
     $this->currency->set('USD');
     $sec = "1";
     var_dump($_SESSION['shipping_zone_id']);
     exit (header("Refresh: $sec; url=index.php?route=checkout/checkout"));
     }

Comment: Don't add anything to `exit`. Remove `refresh` line at all

Comment: This is what i applied , noting happen : $this->currency->set('MYR'); 
  if ($_SESSION['shipping_zone_id'] == '3528'){ 
$this->currency->set('USD'); 
var_dump($_SESSION['shipping_zone_id']); 
header("url=index.php?route=checkout/checkout"); 
exit;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the lines of of code below

```
$this->currency->set('MYR'); 
 if ($_SESSION['shipping_zone_id'] == '3528'){ 
 $this->currency->set('USD');


 if(!empty($_GET['refresh']) && $_GET['refresh'] == 0 ){} //add this
else{

 $sec = "10";
 header("Refresh: $sec; url=index.php?refresh=0&route=checkout/checkout");

 } //and close it here

 }
```